# Node.js npm installing websocket fails

Tags: node.js, websocket, npm

I am installing websocket through npm in Windows 7 64 bit. The websocket version is 1.0.8

I am getting a linking error even though I have Visual Studio 2010 and Python 2.7 :

```
C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\websocket>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\n
ode_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" r
ebuild
  validation.cc
C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\0.10.30\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506: no d
efinition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::Hand
le<T>)' [C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\websocket\build\validation.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\w
ebsocket\build\Release\validation.node' [C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\websoc
ket\build\validation.vcxproj]
  xor.cpp
C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\0.10.30\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no d
efinition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::Hand
le<T>)' [C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\websocket\build\xor.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\w
ebsocket\build\Release\xor.node' [C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\websocket\bui
ld\xor.vcxproj]
gyp[websocket v1.0.8]
    Native code compile failed!!
    Please note that this module DOES NOT REQUIRE the native components
    and will still work without them, though not quite as efficiently.

    On Windows, native extensions require Visual Studio and Python.
    On Unix, native extensions require Python, make and a C++ compiler.
    Start npm with --websocket:verbose to show compilation output (if any).
websocket@1.0.8 node_modules\websocket

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Is there a way to skip this compilation stuff and just use this module right away ? Or someway to fix this error ?

PS: the command prompt was started with Admin rights.

Comment: `Please note that this module DOES NOT REQUIRE the native components and will still work without them, though not quite as efficiently.`

Comment: Yep, would like to fix this error though.

Comment: The module does not seem to work anyway as I get an error when I try to use it : module.js:340 throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'websocket' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)  at Module.require module.js:364:17)  at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.<anonymous> (P:\Code\Javascript\nodejs\server.js:2:23) at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)